# JavaScript casts keys with numerical strings to Numbers... but Object.keys() doesn't

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

An external API returns a JSON result of the following form:

```
{
    "data": {
        "1.0": 'foo',
        "2.3": 'bar',
        "3.6": 'baz'
    }
}
```

Here, the keys `"1.0", "2.3", "3.6"` should really be taken as strings denoting a discrete categorisation, **not** as values along a continuous axis. It is therefore perfectly valid for this API to return these keys as strings.

However... (you can feel it coming, aren't you?)

In the JS client, I need to iterate over these keys and here comes the trouble:

- the browser's JS engine automatically casted all these keys into `Number`
- using `Object.keys(myObject.data)` returns... strings!
- therefore, the following does not work **at all** as you can see:

```js
let myObject = {
  "data": {
    "1.0": 'foo',
    "2.3": 'bar',
    "3.6": 'baz'
  }
}

console.log(myObject.data)
for (let k in Object.keys(myObject.data)) {
  console.log(k, myObject.data[k])
}

// {
//     1.0: 'foo',
//     2.3: 'bar',
//     3.6: 'baz
// }
// "1.0" undefined
// "2.3" undefined
// "3.6" undefined
```

It seems that we have two conflicting things here: first, the object keys are converted into Numbers, but at the same time, `Object.keys()` returns Strings instead of Numbers.

Is there an appropriate way to solve this problem?

Ideally, I'd like the object's actual keys to remain strings, as they should be. Casting the values from `Object.keys()` into Numbers would lead to quite cumbersome workarounds as the API can (and does) return "real" strings as keys sometimes (like `{ "red": 'foo', "blue": 'bar' }`.

Comment: use for of loop

Comment: `console.log(k, myObject.data[k])` prints out `// 0 undefined 1 undefined ` and not `"1.0" undefined`. Check @CodeManiac's answer. `Object.keys()` returns an array. You can simply use `for (let k in myObject.data){}` instead

Comment: "*the browser's JS engine automatically casted all these keys into Number*" - um, no, what makes you think that? Object keys are *always* strings (or symbols), never numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply do not use `Object.keys`:

```js
let myObject = {
  "data": {
    "1.0": 'foo',
    "2.3": 'bar',
    "3.6": 'baz'
  }
}

console.log(myObject.data)
for (let k in myObject.data) {
  console.log(k, myObject.data[k])
}
```

*Some explanation:*

`Object.keys` does what it says - extracts keys from the passed in object and returns them as array (*in your case that'd be: `[ "1.0", "2.3", "3.6"]`*). So when you are trying to loop over this with `for..in`, you are in fact looping over that resulting array, instead of the actual object and `key` variable will receive an *index* of the corresponding item from the array (*`0` for `"1.0"`, `1` for `"2.3"`, etc*). That's just how `for..in` [works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in). If you would like to loop over the values of the array instead, you could use `for..of` [as another option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Or in your case, as I've mentioned above, simply do not use `Object.keys`.

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is `for in`

for in tries to access keys in array created by `Object.keys(obj.data)` which is actually index

```js
let obj = {"data": {"1.0": 'foo',"2.3": 'bar',"3.6": 'baz'}}

Object.keys(obj.data).forEach(e=>{
  console.log(typeof e)
})

//You can simply drop of Object.keys 

for (let k in obj.data) {
  console.log(k, obj.data[k])
}
```

Comment: Can you reference an authoritative source for this?

Comment: @jayarjo [array iteration using for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)

Comment: Your concise way of formulating answers confused me. Of course they are indices, but of the array, and not the object.

Comment: It will be useful if you add `for (let k in myObject.data) { }` to the answer

Comment: @jayarjo `for in tries to access keys in array created by Object.keys(obj.data) which is actually index` i have specified array here

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the `for..in` loop, try `for..of` to solve this issue. The `for..in` loop will iterate over all enumerable properties of the object itself and those the object inherits from its constructor's prototype.

Whereas `for..of` on the other hand, is mainly interested in values of iterable objects in this case it is an array returned by the `Object.keys()` call.

```js
var myObject = {
    "data": {
        "1.0": 'foo',
        "2.3": 'bar',
        "3.6": 'baz'
    }
}
console.log(myObject.data)
for (let k of Object.keys(myObject.data)) {
    console.log(k, myObject.data[k])
}
```

Here when you are iterating through the `Object.keys(myObject.data)`, it is considering the indices(keys of array object) of the returned array instead of the actual values of `myObject.data` array.

Here is the distinction with a small example:

```js
var arr = [10, 20, 30];
console.log("**for - in loop**")
//logs indices 0, 1, 2
for (i in arr){
  console.log(i);
}
console.log("**for - of loop**")
//logs values in the array 10, 20, 30
for (i of arr){
  console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: That's not a valid distinction between `for...in` and `for..of`.